# Create Deployment Permission for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have automation around an API Gateway deployment:

```
aws apigateway create-deployment ...
```

I am attempting to wrap my features in continuous deployment and I cannot seem to understand the IAM permissions which seem to deviate from all other IAM permissions across other services:

- `apigateway:GET`
- `apigateway:PUT`
- `apigateway:POST`
- `apigateway:DELETE`
- `apigateway:PATCH`
- `apigateway:OPTIONS`

([Cloudonaut Documentation](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/apigateway.html); ["Control Access for Managing an API"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-create-and-manage-api.html#api-gateway-iam-policy-resource-format-for-managing-api))

Permissions only seem to cover stages:

- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/*`**
  for all resources, methods, models, and stages in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/*`**
  for all resources, methods, models, and stages in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/resources/resource-id/*`**
  for all resources and methods in the resource with the identifier resource-id, which is in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/resources/resource-id/methods/*`**
  for all of the methods in the resource with the identifier resource-id, which is in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/resources/resource-id/methods/GET`**
  for just the GET method in the resource with the identifier resource-id, which is in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/models/*`**
  for all of the models in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/models/model-name`**
  for the model with the name of model-name, which is in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/stages/*`**
  for all of the stages in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.
- **`arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/stages/stage-name`**
  for just the stage with the name of stage-name in the API with the identifier of api-id in the AWS region of region.

How do I grant the ability to create a deployment for a given stage? `apigateway:PUT`? `apigateway:POST`?

Answer (score 2):

By testing, I have elucidated the policy required:

```
{
    "Action": "apigateway:POST",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/${rest_api_id}/deployments",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": "AllowApiGatewayDeployments"
}
```

It may not be possible to limit the deployment to a given stage, but I don't know because I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`{
   "Action": "apigateway:POST",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis/*/stages/${stage_name}",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Sid": "VisualEditor"
}`